# Is it safe to use String.prototype.toUpperCase() or String.prototype.toLowerCase() on numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, string, character-encoding, alphanumeric

I have some dynamic strings which might contain numeric characters too. E.g. `1sFw23fD`. I want to convert all letters in this string to capitals. That is I want to convert `1sFw23fD` into `1SFW23FD`. For that, I am using `toUpperCase()` method. What I am not sure is how is `toUpperCase()` supposed to work on numeric and alphanumeric character. Is it safe to use `"1sFw23fD".toUpperCase()`?

As explained in answer, that numbers aren't affected by these methods. Plz give some reference that mentions such as w3c spec or mdn etc. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As defined in http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-properties-of-the-string-prototype-object , it just replaces characters that have a representing uppercase/lowercase value in the Unicode table. And that shouldnt be wrong...:

*"For each code point c in cpList, if the Unicode Character Database provides a language insensitive lower case equivalent of c then replace c in cpList with that equivalent code point(s)."*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned there's nothing wrong with doing what you're doing now.

```
> "123123123123a".toUpperCase()
'123123123123A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's safe. It only affects characters of the appropriate case and leaves the rest alone.

Edit: "The toUpperCase method has no effect on non-alphabetic characters." Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/touppercase-method-string-javascript

Comment: Do you any reference that mention that numbers aren't affected by these string methods?

Comment: Sure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/touppercase-method-string-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use that. It this case "1sFw23fD" is already a string>Note the quotes around it .

You can also use css property `text-align:uppercase`

```css
.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class='uppercase'>
  1sFw23fD
</div>
```